# View table style sort options - custom alternative to Ascending or Descending

Tags: 7, views

I have a view that is displayed as a table. In Format > Settings I can set some fields (columns) to be sortable. The Default Order can then be set to Ascending or Descending. How can I define a custom sort method so that it shows up in that dropdown?

Comment: Views delegate sorting to database. Most databases only have two ways of sorting, asc and desc. Could you describe some example of another sorting, and maybe how do you imagine it to work? Loading all results to memory and sorting in PHP? I hope not, I think that's server killer, but don't have any other idea, really.

Comment: I'm thinking of ignoring certain starting characters in a string. I guess this should be handled by the field before it gets to the sort. In principle though, perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8174026) is another sorting.